# bidirectional beans synchronization

Tags: java, properties, javabeans

How to implement bidirectional sinchronization between two bound properties? The utility class PropertyChangeSupport provides a trivial mechanism that avoids infinite loop. In some cases I find it to be insufficient. Is there a better alternative?

Take the simplest possible class with a String bounded property:

```
private String myProperty;
//obviuos getter and setter omitted. (ok, setter contains propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange. should be obvious the same)


public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
   //delegate to propertyChangeSupport
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
   //delegate to propertyChangeSupport
}
```

ok.
Now I try to use notifications in order to perform bidirectional sincronization between this property value, owned by two instances of this class.

This is the (quite simple) code:

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {

    final T01 o1 = new T01();

    final T01 o2 = new T01();

    o1.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            o2.setMyProperty(o1.getMyProperty());
        }
    });

      o2.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            o1.setMyProperty(o2.getMyProperty());
        }
    });

    o1.setMyProperty("test");

}
```

Here there is no infinite loop, because the PropertyChangeSupport suppress the notification when it turns back to the originating class, because the oldValue is equal than the newValue. 
IMHO this is a "trivial" implementation, while a better principle may be that "an event should NOT be notified to the class that has caused it".

The problems with this implementation based on "equal values" are: 
 1. raises a unnecessary, redundant event to the originating class of the change (that THEN the originating class suppresses) 
 2. suppresses the event when the oldvalue equals newvalue also if it is a new one and not a "turning back" one. In most cases the suppression is correct, but in some (rare) cases the event may however be useful. Be itself "informative". Think to a timeout that has to be cleared each time an event is received.  
 3. it has a "strange" implementation. If you do:

```
o1.setMyProperty(null);  <br/>
```

you get the infinite loop and the consequent stackoverflow.
Because the event is suppressed if the values are equals AND not null. But "null" is in many cases a legitimate value.

Comment: The problem is not the bean property model, but what you are trying to do with them.  If all your `T01` instances share the same `myProperty`, make is a static member.  If you can't use that particular solution, you must nonetheless redesign your code to get rid of any bidirectional property change.

Comment: Dear toto, sometimes asking a question you have to explain why the "current" implementation is not sufficient. If you read carefully my question you'll see that is a list of facts, and not opinions. Moreover, questions on "improvements" are necessarily more verbose than basic-feautres requests.

Comment: @Toto: static means a value for all instances. I'm talking about just two instances and not necessarily of the same class type. Like happens for a data model and its view. Here I used a same-class properties in order to provide a simpler sample, but in the case of a data class (pojo style) and a gui class (say JFrame extension) with properties representing controls, the core would be exactly the same. In some cases (JCheckBox) the MVC pattern is not available or too complex to implement.

Comment: If you are asking this question related to Swing, you should add it in the tags. Something does not feel quite right to me if you put a bidirectional bound property between a Swing component and the model. There are obvious issues with synchronization, but it also seems to me that the view and model are too tightly coupled. I would like to see the opinion of more advanced Swing developers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [jGoodies Binding Library](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html) and the [PropertyConnector](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jgoodies/binding/2.0.6/binding-2.0.6-javadoc.jar!/com/jgoodies/binding/beans/PropertyConnector.html):

```
final T01 o1 = new T01();
final T01 o2 = new T01();
PropertyConnector.connect(o1, "myProperty", o2, "myProperty").updateProperty2();
```

Now the bound property `myProperty` of `o1` will be synchronized with `o2` and vice versa.

Comment: I don't like JGoodies, since it's paid suite. I'm willing to pay in order to get something more respect to the standard. But in this specific case, I'm not buying JGodies for the swing advanced components, but in order to fix the beans model (or to fix my lack of knowledge of it).

Comment: Secondary, I don't like the "fixing model". All the official documentation about java and swing presents it as something very advanced. The expectation is to "have a lot to study", but not to have to buy some "aid" tools. If the eventual solution is this, i'll before evaluate other "all-in-one" solutions like MyEclipse that (by paing) promise all what you legitimately expect to develop and not just a fix.

Comment: The Bindings library (stand alone) is BSD licensed and may be downloaded and used for no charge (which we do at my work). The Swing Suite (containing bindings lib + a lot other) on the other hand, you have to pay for.